# How to know whether a call is made or not using AT Command terminal output

Tags: embedded, at-command

I am using SIM908 (it includes a GPS and GSM modem in one module) to call someone.
I issued the ATD command along with the phone number to call. 
Sometimes it will call, and in sometimes it wont.

I will get a "NO CARRIER" reply when the other end cuts the call after conversation or the device is not reachable/switched off.

I will get "BUSY" reply when the other end cuts the call while ringing.

My problem is, I want to distinguish whether the call is actually made or not. Since I am getting "NO CARRIER" for both, I can't use that as an indicator.

Anybody have an efficient way to detect whether the call is actually made or not.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience with AT, there's no way to do that 'in runtime'. But you can check the 'response' RING from the console.